# How can I prevent the MaterialUI Switch from animating?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, material-ui

I'm new to React and making a Chrome extension with it.

Currently, I am using the Switch component from MaterialUI inside my popup page. How I am saving its state right now is by storing the state of each change in chrome.storage.local API. When I click back to the pop-up, I simply use the useEffect hook & fetch the state from chrome.storage.local & pass it as an argument to setState().

My issue with this is that it causes the toggle button to animate from off to on very briefly when you reopen the popup (as if you were manually toggling it). I'm aware it's because of the way I'm doing it (i.e, initializing the state of the toggle as false each time the pop-up is opened) but I'm currently stumped on doing this another way. Could anyone please help me? Thanks for reading!

MySwitchComponent.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Switch } from '@material-ui/core/';

const StyledSwitch = withStyles({
  root: {
    position: 'relative',
    marginTop: '20px',
    marginLeft: '90px'
  },
})(Switch);

export default function NewSwitch() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(false)

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState(event.target.checked);
    chrome.storage.local.set({auto_delete_toggle: event.target.checked });
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(res){
      setState(res.auto_delete_toggle);
    })
  });

  return (
    <StyledSwitch
    checked={state}
    onChange={handleChange}
    > 
    </StyledSwitch>)
 
}
```

My popup.js just renders all the components encapsulated in a single  in popup.html. Also, chrome.storage.local.get is asynchronous.

EDIT:
Here is a GIF to better illustrate my issue:
[image: Toggle Button unwanted reanimation]

Comment: One approach is to return `null` (i.e. don't render the switch) until you know the initial state for the switch. You can manage this by either having a separate state boolean for whether or not you have read from local storage yet or by having 3 values for your state (e.g. `undefined`, `false`, `true`) and leave it as `undefined` until checking local storage.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks for the reply. Firstly, I don't think your second suggestion would work since MaterialUI is raising a warning when I initialize the state as undefined—Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).

Comment: @RyanCogswell Secondly: I'm not really understanding. I was under the impression that I was rendering the switch once I accessed local.storage, since it is going from the initial state (false) to the stored state (true). Could you explain further? Also, I added a GIF to help illustrate my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, here's a sandbox that reproduces your issue. I've used a `mockAsyncStorage` (which is backed by `window.localStorage`) to mimic the async `chrome.storage.local.get`. You can see the undesired transition by clicking the switch so that it is checked, and then refreshing the page.

```
import React from "react";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import mockAsyncStorage from "./mockAsyncStorage";
export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
    mockAsyncStorage.set({ auto_delete_toggle: event.target.checked });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    mockAsyncStorage.get(null, function(res) {
      setChecked(
        res.auto_delete_toggle === undefined ? false : res.auto_delete_toggle
      );
    });
  }, []);
  return <Switch checked={checked} onChange={handleChange} />;
}
```

[image: Edit Switch async init]

Below is one way to get rid of the transition. This initializes `checked` to `undefined` and while it is still `undefined`, it returns `null` instead of the switch so nothing is rendered until the appropriate initial state of the switch is known.

```
import React from "react";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import mockAsyncStorage from "./mockAsyncStorage";
export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(undefined);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
    mockAsyncStorage.set({ auto_delete_toggle: event.target.checked });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    mockAsyncStorage.get(null, function(res) {
      setChecked(
        res.auto_delete_toggle === undefined ? false : res.auto_delete_toggle
      );
    });
  }, []);
  if (checked === undefined) {
    return null;
  }
  return <Switch checked={checked} onChange={handleChange} />;
}
```

[image: Edit Switch async init]

Comment: Oh, I see now! Your answer taught me a lot, thanks!